# How to filter wp_get_recent_posts() to only posts that have thumbnails?

Tags: filters, hooks, post-thumbnails, thumbnails, recent-posts

I made a script that shows recent posts. But here's the problem, I want to show only posts that have thumbnails, and I want to show at least 10 posts if there are that many without thumbnails. So the filtering needs to happen before fetching 10 recent posts, because otherwise there's a possibility that none of them could have thumbnails and nothing will show.

Here's my code:

```
function add_before_my_siderbar() {
  // get recent posts
  $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts();
  foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ) {

       // Print recent posts

  }
}

add_action( 'get_my_sb_widget', 'add_before_my_siderbar' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass arguments to pass `meta_query` to your `wp_get_recent_posts()` function. `wp_get_recent_posts()` makes call for `get_posts()`, so you can make use of all the arguments `get_posts()` or `WP_Query` uses. As per your need.

```
$args= array(
        'meta_query' => array(array('key' => '_thumbnail_id')) 
);
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args);
```

Along with other arguments you want to pass to your function.

Please check for proper syntax. Haven't tried the code.